# what displays (among VGA, HDMI, DVI) can a device with a micro HDMI port connect to?

Tags: display, hdmi, vga, dvi

If my device (phone or tablet) had a micro HDMI port, then which of the following can I connect it to (using cables and adapters)?

- A monitor with a VGA port
- A monitor with a DVI port
- A monitor with a regular HDMI port
- A monitor with a mini HDMI port

Somebody made a claim that Microsoft Surface has mini DisplayPort on it so that it can connect to any kind of display and that made me wonder this question.

Comment: That somebody made an accurate statement provided you have the required cables.  There are Mini-Hdmi to Hdmi cables.  There are HDMI to DVI cables and there are HDMI to VGA cables.

Comment: Ever heard of this: http://justgit.com/?q=mini%20displayport%20adapter

Comment: Not sure why some think this is not a good question. I read an article comparing HDMI and DisplayPort and it said that a DisplayPort's pro was that a device with mini DisplayPort can connect to any display. Because I am a newbie, it just seems natural to wonder what kind of display a device with micro HDMI cannot connect to after reading that article

Answer (score 0):

All of the above, one way or another.

Search for Mini DisplayPort to VGA, DVI, HDMI, etc., and you should find an appropriate adapter to fit the bill.

Here's an example of a page listing a bunch of adapters: http://www.monoprice.com/Category?c_id=104&cp_id=10428

Comment: That's for mini Displayport. The question was about whether a device with micro HDMI port could connect to all as well.